# Simpler way to compute gravity?

Tags: physics

I have code for a simple n-body problem:

```
GravityForce[pos1_, pos2_] := (pos1 - pos2)/
   EuclideanDistance[pos1, pos2]^2;
GravityForce[p_, p_] := {0, 0, 0};
Forces[pos_List] := With[{n = Length[pos]},
   Mean /@ Table[GravityForce[pos[[i]], pos[[j]]], {i, n}, {j, n}]
   ];
n = 10;
{vel, pos} = RandomReal[{-20, 20}, {2, n, 3}];
vel += -7 Forces[pos] - 10 (GravityForce[#, sun] & /@ pos);
pos += vel
```

Is there some way to make this simpler?

Comment: `pos += vel`??! What units are you working in here?

Comment: Why not use NDSolve in first place to solve the differential equations?

Comment: I believe your `Table` can be done as `Outer[GravityForce, pos, pos]`.  I think you need to divide by `r` in `GravityForce` if you intend to direct your force along  a *unit vector* by the way (although studying your physics problem is outside the scope of this forum..)

Comment: I believe it should be `EuclideanDistance[pos1, pos2]^3` not `^2`...

Comment: @george2079 f[p] === Outer[g, p, p]

Comment: @BlacKow you're right.

Comment: @march unitless

Comment: sorry @george2079 I meant to say f[p] != Outer[g, p, p]

Comment: I meant just the `Table` , so `Mean/@Outer[]`

Comment: @george2079 Ah I see, also Outer[g,p,p,1] works

Comment: yes, the `1` arg is needed, sorry I forgot that. As a physics matter shouldn't it be `Total` not `Mean` ?

Comment: NDSolve would be a better option here. I've done stuff like this (https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-trajectory.m but it's hideously ugly), and the coefficient 3/2 seems to come up naturally. I think your equations are oversimplified, and, as others note, `pos2-pos1` is fine for direction, but you need to divide it by its own norm to get the unit vector.